# Tkinter Scrollbar works but scrollbar isnt visible

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar, scrollable

I have a scrollable text frame that scrolls properly, however, the scrollbar is not visible and im not sure why. I think it is because of the way im doing the scrollbar.pack but im not sure how to change it to get it to appear properly.

```
    helpWin = Toplevel(root)
    helpWin.title('')
    helpWin.geometry("650x375")
    helpWin.resizable(False, False)

    helpFrame = Frame(helpWin)
    helpFrame.place(x = 0, y = 0)

    scrollbar = Scrollbar(helpFrame, orient = VERTICAL)
    help_area = Text(helpFrame, wrap = Tkinter.WORD, font=('Georgia', 8), bg=bgColor, fg='black', yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command = help_area.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side = 'right', fill = "y")
    help_area.pack(side = "left", fill = "y", padx = (10,0), pady = 15)
```

Output Window:
[image]

Comment: Your Text widget seems wider than your window, so your scrollbar is not in the visible area of your window.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get it to fill the whole screen but not the area where the scrollbar would be?

Comment: For me, a good rule of thumb is to never turn the ability to resize a window off. When debugging layout issues it's very valuable to be able to resize a window to see if there are widgets hiding on the edges. In production, users should have control over the size of the windows on their desktop.

Comment: If you require that the window be a specific size, make the text widget 1x1 and then use the options to `pack` to get it to fill all available space.

Comment: @Charles Urban. If you want to use ScrollText. then you don't need Scrollbar